# Have all of the 3 Game of Thrones twists been revealed?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In [this TIME article](http://time.com/4346408/game-of-thrones-george-r-r-martin-3-twists/) it was mentioned that George R.R. Martin shared 3 major twists with the *Game of Thrones* showrunners:

> Showrunners David Benioff and D.B. Weiss recently told Entertainment Weekly that during a 2013 meeting with Martin, they learned about “three holy sh— moments” the Song of Ice and Fire author intended to include in his series — two of which have already happened.
>
> The first took place in the ninth episode of season five, when Stannis agreed to allow Melisandre to burn his daughter Shireen. The second was, of course, the revelation in Sunday’s episode that Bran Stark was the cause of both Hodor’s condition and death. And the third? Well, the third, “is from the very end,” Benioff told EW.

In S08E03, "The Long Night", the Night king is killed. Does this mean all 3 twists have been revealed? Do we know if the Night King's death was the last of the 3 twists?

Comment: The revelation that Jon is a Targaryen and the true heir to the throne isn't a holy sh*t moment? Ok then...

Comment: @gustavo: that was actually one of the widest believed book theories with multiple hints in the books itself (including even subtle hints towards him being legitimate and not a bastard) Big deal: yes, surprise: not really.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## No.

There are various reasons why the Night King's death isn't the third holy s**t moment, and they are summarized nicely in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/bivv6b/spoilers_extended_the_third_holy_shit_moment_has/?depth=1):

> The very end, you say? I think it’s clear that the final moments of
> Episode 3, Arya delivering the killing blow to the Night’s King, isn’t
> the third holy shit moment GRRM revealed to the showrunners. It’s
> clearly shocking (also controversial), but it doesnt fulfill the
> criteria. Why?
>
> The Night’s King, as a character, does not have a direct equivalent in
> the books. He is a show-creation.
>
> Yesterday after the episode aired, the showrunners revealed that they
> decided to have Arya kill the Night’s King about three years ago. It
> seems like this was completely a choice of their own volition, but if
> you want to see more check out this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/bij9w0/spoilers_extended_dd_made_the_character_choice/) by [/u/Fat_Walda](https://www.reddit.com/u/Fat_Walda)
>
> Benioff and Weiss had no qualms about revealing that the other two
> “holy shit” moments were from GRRM, so why would they play coy with
> the third if it was Arya killing the Night’s King?

So, it's very likely that the third twist has yet to come.

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson may I ask what's wrong with markdown there>

Comment: Nothing's inherently "wrong", but it's worth streamlining the answer a little. You're giving an introduction to the post anyway, so there's no need for a tedious full link at the end in its own paragraph in addition to that. But feel free to roll it back if you're uncomfortable with the edit.

Comment: Has it come now?